# Capure js click button over another button

Tags: javascript

I have a button over another button in a way like this

```
<button id="button1" style="width:200px; height:200px; position:relative; border: 1px solid;">

    <a href="#" id="button2" style="position: absolute; border:1px solid;">test</a>
</button>

<script>

    document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function(e) {  
        console.log("button1 click");
    }

    document.getElementById("button2").onclick = function(e) {  
        console.log("button2 click");
    }

</script>
```

When I click on button2, also the button1 is clicked, but I would only capture button2 click

Tried with **e.preventDefault()** without success...

Comment: Must be why nesting an anchor inside a button is invalid HTML....

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, an `<a>` element cannot be wrapped inside a `<button>` element.

Comment: You can use `e.stopPropagation()` on the event for `button2`, but you should rethink your design instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think it's not valid HTML. You shouldn't have a `<a>` tag inside `<button>`

For more information about `<button>` check [this](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/the-button-element.html).

You're facing this problem because of event bubbling. Check this links for more details regarding event bubbling.
https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

You can fix this problem using `event.stopPropagation();` But I must say it's not the right approach

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of bubbling. Event runs the handlers on every parent all the way up. You could do something like this to fix this.

```
<button id="button1" style="width:200px; height:200px; position:relative; border: 1px solid;">
    <a href="#" id="button2" style="position: absolute; border:1px solid;">test</a>
</button>

<script>  
    document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function(e) {  
        console.log("button1 click");
    }

    document.getElementById("button2").onclick = function(e) {  
        console.log("button2 click");
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

</script>
```